# Errors with vector class

Tags: c++, class, vector

I'm attempting to create a program that takes the input of a file and then stores the words into a vector, so far I have got it working with the std::vector class, though I wanted to try to make my own, to use. I have been getting quite a few error however and not sure how to solve them.

Error Messages:

```
main.cpp:43: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before "Vector"
main.cpp:43: error: expected `;' before "Vector"
main.cpp:47: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before "Vector"
main.cpp:47: error: expected `;' before "Vector"
main.cpp:55: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before "Vector"
main.cpp:55: error: expected `;' before "Vector"
main.cpp: In function `int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:115: error: expected primary-expression before "auto"
main.cpp:115: error: expected `;' before "auto"
main.cpp:116: error: expected primary-expression before "auto"
main.cpp:118: error: no matching function for call to `std::vector<WordInfo, std::allocator<WordInfo> >::push_back(std::string&, int)'
```

My code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct WordInfo {
    string text;
    int count;
};

template <class T> class Vector {
public:
    typedef T* iterator;
    Vector();
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();
    int size();
    iterator insert(iterator position, const T& item);
    void alloc_new();

private:
    T items[1000];
    int used;
};

template <class T> Vector<T>::Vector() {

    used = 0;
}

template <class T> Vector<T>::iterator Vector<T>::begin() {
    return items;
}

template <class T> Vector<T>::iterator Vector<T>::end() {
    return items + used;
}

template <class T> int Vector<T>::size() {
    return used;
}

template <class T> Vector<T>::iterator Vector<T>::insert(iterator position, const T& item) {

    if (used + 1 > items) {
        alloc_new();
    }

    items[position] = item;
    used = +1;

}

template <class T> void Vector<T>::alloc_new() {
    items = used * 2;
    T tmp[] = items;

    for (int i = 0; i < used; i++) {
        tmp[i] = items[i];
    }
    delete items;
    items = tmp;
}

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    enum {
        total, unique, individual
    } mode = total;
    for (int c; (c = getopt(argc, argv, "tu")) != -1;) {
        switch (c) {
            case 't': mode = total;
                break;
            case 'u': mode = unique;
                break;
            case 'i': mode = individual;
                break;

        }
    }
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;
    string word;
    vector<string> list;
    int count = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    while (cin >> word) {
        count += 1;

        if (find(list.begin(), list.end(), word) != list.end()) {
            list.push_back(word);

        }

    }


    switch (mode) {
        case total: cout << "Total " << count << endl;
            break;
        case unique: cout << "Unique " << count2 << endl;
            break;
        case individual:
            vector<WordInfo> list;
            while (cin >> word) {
                if (find(list.begin(), list.end(), word) != list.end()) {
                    auto = find(list.begin(), list.end(), word);
                    list.at(auto).count++;
                } else {
                    list.push_back(word, 1);
                }
            }
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: You might want to start by deciding if its vector or Vector.

Comment: `alloc_new` doesn't have a hope of working; the class contains an array, not a pointer to a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: Do you have any reason to not use a proper data structure from the standard library? Because your attempts at the moment are quite hopelessly confused. It's probably best to figure out how to do what you want using standard solutions, before attempting to implement those datastructures _at the same time_

Comment: I have **[added a demo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19439859/85371)** of how you'd use `std::map` and standard library algorithms to implement the intended features

Comment: Also note, your getopt doesn't actually allow the user to pass `-i` yet. Fixed that too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to qualify the return types as typenames:

```
template <class T> typename /* <---- THIS */
    Vector<T>::iterator Vector<T>::begin() 
{
    return items;
}
```

Because the iterator is a dependent name. It's probably more idiomatic to implement these methods in-class, though (template methods require the definition to be in the header file anyways).

Also:

```
                auto = find(list.begin(), list.end(), word);
                list.at(auto).count++;
```

Should be something like

```
                auto match = find(list.begin(), list.end(), word);
                list.at(match - list.begin()).count++;
```

---

### Using the Standard Library

As per [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439773/errors-with-vector-class/19439859#comment28823171_19439773), I'd recommend doing things with standard library containers (at least, before attempting to implement the containers as well). Here's what that looks like:

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2a99f7d7d4dc0a0)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>
#include <getopt.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    enum {
        total, unique, individual
    } mode = total;

    for (int c; (c = getopt(argc, argv, "tui")) != -1;) {
        switch (c) {
            case 't': mode = total;
                break;
            case 'u': mode = unique;
                break;
            case 'i': mode = individual;
                break;
        }
    }

    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    map<string, unsigned> tally;

    unsigned long total_count = 0;
    for_each(
            istream_iterator<string>(cin), {}, 
            [&] (std::string const& word) mutable 
            { 
                tally[word]++; 
                total_count++; 
            }
        );

    switch (mode) {
        case total: 
            cout << "Total " << total_count << endl;
            break;
        case unique: 
            cout << "Unique " << tally.size() << endl;
            break;
        case individual:
            for (auto const& entry: tally)
                cout << entry.first << "\t" << entry.second << "\n";
            break;
    }
}
```

With input.txt

```
apple pear jumped over the apple moon 
blob the cow blob jumped over the apple moan grumpy dog apple
```

This is the output:

- **`test -t < input.txt`**

  ```
  Total 19
  ```
- **`test -u < input.txt`**

  ```
  Unique 11
  ```
- **`test -i < input.txt`**

  ```
  apple   4
  blob    2
  cow 1
  dog 1
  grumpy  1
  jumped  2
  moan    1
  moon    1
  over    2
  pear    1
  the 3
  ```